# Concept behind Float datatype and its assignment

Tags: c, floating-point, type-conversion

Kindly explain me the output/concept behind these 2 pieces of code.

```
float x;
x=(float)3.3==3.3;
printf("%f",x);
```

The output for above is 0.000000

```
float x;
x=(float)3.5==3.5;
printf("%f",x);
```

The output for above is 1.000000

Comment: Write `3.3` and `3.5` in binary. Remember `double` has more precision than `float`.

Comment: I don't know what was your concept behind assigning bool value to float variable.

Comment: Also: **always use `double`; don't use `float` without a good reason** (because the teacher said so is not a good reason)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C source text, the numeral “3.3” stands for a value of the double type that is very close to the number 3.3. Good compilers convert “3.3” to the value of the double type that is closest to 3.3, which is 3.29999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875, but the C standard does not require that.

The expression `(float) 3.3` converts this double to float, which produces the value of the float type that is closest to the double. That value is 3.2999999523162841796875.

Then the expression `(float) 3.3 == 3.3` compares the float value to the double value. (This implicitly converts the float to double, but the value does not change during this conversion.) Since the values are inequal, the result of the comparison is 0.

Since 3.5 is exactly representable as a double, the numeral “3.5” produces exactly the value 3.5. This is also exactly representable as a float, so converting it to float produces 3.5. Then comparing the two values produces 1.

(This answer assumes IEEE 754 floating point, which is very common.)

Answer (score 1):

`3.3` is not exactly representable in binary floating point (it contains a recurring fractional part).  Converting the `double` literal `3.3` to `float` and back to `double` for comparison to `3.3` loses precision, so the comparison is unequal.

For IEEE 64-bit `double` and 32-bit `float`:

- The literal `3.3` is represented as `0x1.a666666666666p+1`
- The literal `3.3f` is represented as `0x1.a66666p+1`, so `(float) 3.3` will be the same
- Promoted back to double, we get `0x1.a666660000000p+1`, which is clearly unequal to `3.3`.

`3.5` on the other hand is exactly representable in both `float` and `double` (as `0x1.cp+1`), so the comparison is equal.

Comparisons result in either `1` (for equal) or `0` (for unequal), and you are printing out the result of the comparison as a floating-point number.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the 1st paragraph of your answer?

Comment: @AmitAgarwal Please take a look at this link: http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e85/lectures/arithmetic_html/node11.html and then go to section "Examples of IEEE 754". Very good answer btw.

Comment: This is slightly inaccurate; it is not the fact that 3.3 is not exactly representable in binary floating point that causes this problem but rather the fact that the double produced from the source text “3.3” is not exactly representable as a float. For example, 7.000000476837158203126 is not exactly representable in binary floating point but produces 1 in the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

`3.3` is not a `float` but a `double`: you are comparing numbers with different precisions.

Comment: then why is the result different for 3.5?

Comment: The values are converted to the same type before the comparison

Comment: @pmg `(float)3.3==3.3`:  in the left operand of `==` the value `3.3` is converted to `float` and then to `double` while in the right operand no conversion occurs.

Comment: The precision of `(double)(float)3.3` and of `3.3` is the same (~15 digits). Their values are different though.