# Type Conversion Output

Tags: c, type-conversion

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    float x;
    x = (float)3.3==3.3;
    printf("%f",x);

    x=(float)3.5==3.5;
    printf("\n%f",x);
}
```

i'm confused with
in the first case answer is 0.000
and in the second case answer is 1.00
can anyone explain ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concept behind Float datatype and its assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003279/concept-behind-float-datatype-and-its-assignment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the right side numbers are typecasted to doubles not floats.  In order for both cases to print 1, you need to either change the float typecast to double or typecast the second number as a float:

```
float x;
x = (float)3.3==(float)3.3;
printf("%f",x);
x=(float)3.5==(float)3.5;
printf("\n%f",x);
```

or:

```
float x;
x = (double)3.3==3.3;
printf("%f",x);
x=(double)3.5==3.5;
printf("\n%f",x);
```

Answer (score 4):

The expression

```
(float)3.3==3.3
```

first casts the `double` value 3.3 to `float` precision, thereby changing its value, since it's not exactly representable in the target type. Then that `float` value is converted back to `double`, without changing the value` for the comparison, resulting in the comparison returning 0 (false). 3.5 is exactly representable in both types, so there the comparison returns true (1).

Then in both cases the `int` result of the comparison is converted to `float` for the assignment.

Comment: why 3.3 is double and 3.5 both double and float

Comment: Both constants have type `double`, `3.3f` and `3.5f` would be `float` constants. But the value 3.5 is exactly representable as a `float`, so neither the cast to `float` nor the conversion back to `double` change the value.

Comment: @java: For the same reason that 3 as an integer equals 3 as a double. Both integer and double can represent 3 exactly. But, if you cast 3.3 to an integer and compare the result to 3.3, they will be unequal, because the conversion produces 3, and 3 does not equal 3.3. Similarly, both float and double can represent 3.5 exactly, because the floating-point you are using is binary based, so it can represent numbers like 4, 2, 1, 1/2, and 1/4 exactly (as long as the bits stay within certain ranges). 3.3 cannot be represented exactly, and float has fewer bits, so converting 3.3 to float changes it.